# Font issue in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios6

I have set the font to label.  Use Storyboard property to set the font. 
Font i have used Helvetica Neue 16.0 This one. It works for iOS 7. But this font will not be applicable to iOS 6 why this happening.

[image: Set font like this]

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Helvetica Neue is available in iOS6. Are you sure about the mentioned iOS version?

Comment: i tried like you said and it is working fine for me in both iOS 6 &7.

Comment: yes its not seen in iOS 6

Comment: Then there might be some other issue.

Comment: check if you are resetting font via code also.

Comment: i am not doing this.